# How to weight paint complicated meshes?

Tags: weight-painting

I'm trying to make wings. I want to animate them later so I have to rig and weight paint it.

Does anyone know if there is a simple way to weight paint the space between the layers of feathers? Or ho to make it simpler in another way[image]

Comment: Is the wing one mesh object or a number of unjoined mesh objects?

Comment: Currently it is 7 sepperate meches. but I will unite them before I weight paint it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I read that you have to turn of Front faces only and activate 2d falloff.
Then all of the sides of the mech will be painted. [image]